# Material UI – Single or Multiple `MuiThemeProvider` for components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a scenario where my project is split into two repositories, `{WEBSITE}` and `{COMPONENTS}`.

The `{WEBSITE}` handles business logic and data fetching, it also imports `{COMPONENTS}` to feed them the fetched data.

The `{COMPONENTS}` handle the UI theme: colors, fonts, global variables.. and they are pure presentational components.

The typical scenario of MUI usage is to wrap a `<MuiThemeProvider>` around your `<Router>` or `<App>`.

However in my case, `{WEBSITE}` doesn't have `material-ui` installed, therefore no access to `MuiThemeProvider` unless explicitly exported from `{COMPONENTS}/material-ui` (which sounds like an anti-pattern to me)

So in order to style every MUI-component found in `{COMPONENTS}`, I find myself having to export each one of them with the `MuiThemeProvider` like so:

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={sharedThemeBetweenComponents}>
  <Header>
    <AppBar />
  </Header>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={sharedThemeBetweenComponents}>
  <Card />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

---

**Is it recommended to export every single component with an `MuiThemeProvider`? How will this impact the global performance if I have hundred of components on my `{WEBSITE}` pages?**

Comment: All MuiThemeProvider really does is add getChildContext() to your component so it can pass down context.muiTheme to its children. It shouldn't be very expensive at all (although don't bother adding it on components that don't have MUI children). Not really avoidable either. Only workaround would be to provide the method on the components yourself, but that would just bloat your own code and without gaining anything.  https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js

Comment: Why don't you install material-ui in the website repo and make it a peer dependency on the components repo?